# Why are function objects better than function pointers?

Tags: c++, function-object

from [Wikipedia - Function object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object)

> A typical use of a function object is in writing callback functions. A callback in procedural languages, such as C, may be performed by using function pointers.[2] However it can be difficult or awkward to pass a state into or out of the callback function. This restriction also inhibits more dynamic behavior of the function. A function object solves those problems since the function is really a façade for a full object, carrying its own state.

1. Why do function pointers make it difficult to **pass a state into or out of the callback function** and **dynamic behavior of the function**?
2. if function do not use function pointer how programs can called function

Comment: Keep reading your C++ book. When you learn about lambdas, and lambda captures, all will be explained.

Comment: Please clarify: "if function do not use function pointer how programs can called function" - the bad grammar makes it hard to understand what you are asking. People can fix grammar, but first they need to know what you are really asking.

Comment: Calling just a function pointer which uses variables can be tricky because the variables might change while executing the function. To work around this issue a function object copies the state of the variables which are being used into it's own object.

Comment: in general this is an interesting question. But your grammar makes it hard to read. And also as mentioned you stumble across function-object when you learn a bit more about c++.

Comment: 1. Try to pass state into a function using a function pointer and compare the resulting program with another that uses a closure. Which do you find more awkward?

Comment: I this the question OOP vs procedural programming? It is not depending on callbacks, it is depending on objects or not. Sounds like a XY problem description. As written in Wikipedia "A function object solves those problems". And this is not depending on function pointers or any other implementation detail but on using `objects` instead of plain functions and separated data. And this is also is not dependend on the used language. Objects can also be implemented in C or asm.

Comment: Are you asking about `C` or `C++`? Those two are not one and the same, and support different idioms

Comment: @Klaus No, it is about using function objects as callbacks, as opposed to using plain function pointers with no state.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Calling a function or a function object directly or as callback makes no difference. That a call to a function ( directly or via pointer ) can not hold any state is the underlaying problem. Any implementation which points to any kind of an object with state ( data ) while calling the function directly ( eg. this pointer in c++ ) or function object with e.g. operator() can keep the state. So my understanding is simply OOP or not OOP. If it is a function pointer, a vtable offset, called directly or by callback is not important for the question how to keep the state.

Comment: @Klaus I don't see the connection with OOP or vtables but whatever.

Comment: I think this belongs to the programmers stack exchange.

Comment: @IvanRubinson when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As far as function pointers in `C` go, you need to pass the state as an extra parameter. That's in opposition to languages like python, javascript or C++ that have closures. And that means storage duration needs to be considered for that extra structure.
2. C programmers *do* make use of function pointers. And you can't write very generic code without using function pointers. We just apply discipline and pass the captured state in a structure, as a function parameter.

Comment: @juanchopanza, reworded.